Error trying to save video in specific folder inside Movies - Android 13
I need to create an application that records videos and saves them in 2 different folders depending on the button that was pressed to record. However, for some reason the videos are always being saved in "Movies" and not in a folder that I created within "Movies" ("Tipico" or "Atipico").
I noticed that it always saves the recorded videos with the name defined by the system and not with the name I define.
I'm using Android Studio IGuana and the Android version is 13.
This is my manifest and the permissions I released, however the one for writing to files does not appear in the permissions granted to the application
This is my gradle
private void captureVideo(String tipo) {
            if (videoCapture == null) return;

            String name = System.currentTimeMillis() + "";

            ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
            contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, name);
            contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "video/mp4");

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.P){
                contentValues.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.RELATIVE_PATH, "Movies/" + tipo);
            }

            MediaStoreOutputOptions mediaStoreOutputOptions = new MediaStoreOutputOptions.Builder(getContentResolver(),
                MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI).build();

            PendingRecording pendingRecording =  videoCapture.getOutput().prepareRecording(this, mediaStoreOutputOptions);
            recording = pendingRecording.start(ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this), new Consumer<VideoRecordEvent>() {
                @Override
                public void accept(VideoRecordEvent videoRecordEvent) {

                    if (videoRecordEvent instanceof VideoRecordEvent.Start){
                        if (tipo.equals("Tipico")){
                            bVideo.setText("Stop Capture");
                        }else {
                            bFoto.setText("Stop Capture");
                        }
                    } else if (videoRecordEvent instanceof VideoRecordEvent.Finalize ) {

                        if (((VideoRecordEvent.Finalize) videoRecordEvent).hasError()){
                            if (recording != null) recording.stop();
                            recording = null;
                            return;
                        }

                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Video salvo:" + ((VideoRecordEvent.Finalize) videoRecordEvent).getOutputResults().getOutputUri(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                }
            });

    }

I would like to save the videos within their respective folders. But even though I put the correct path, it continues saving in "Movies" only.
enter image description here

I think they android have a bug - check my answer, maybe it will help https://stackoverflow.com/a/64710378/2910319
